# how to get indian 12 hr time using php

Tags: php, date, time

This code get date and time in UK time format but i want INDIAN time format,
plz help

```
echo $today = date("d-m-y / g:i a");
```

Comment: Care to share what the Indian format is for those who aren't Asian...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use date() for this.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'hi_IN');
echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 13, 2010));
```

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: this is not what he wants. or is only a part of what he wants.